# Angular - passing data between components

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, eventemitter

I have three components:

- Date-range-picker-chart
- Date-range-picker-chart-container
- Dashboard

The first two are in a folder, dashboard is in another.

I need to move a variable value from Date-range-picker-chart to Date-range-picker-chart-container.
I tried using EventEmitter but it doesn't go.

**dashboard.html**

```
<div class="col-12 pageTop">
  {{ "menu.dashboard" | translate }}
</div>
<date-range-picker-chart-container
  [searchParamsState]="(searchStatusService.state$ | async).searchParams"
  [searchStatusService]="searchStatusService"
></date-range-picker-chart-container>
<br />
<div class="animated fadeIn">
  <!-- <error-dash-table-container
    [searchParamsState]="(searchStatusService.state$ | async).searchParams"
    [searchStatusService]="searchStatusService"
  ></error-dash-table-container> -->
  <error-chart-container
    [searchParamsState]="(searchStatusService.state$ | async).searchParams"
    [searchStatusService]="searchStatusService"
  ></error-chart-container>
  <error-dash-container></error-dash-container>
</div>
```

**Date-range-picker-chart.ts** (When i click on button search it calls onSearch function that emits,  searchObj contains values that i need to get on the other components.)

```
@Output() search: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
onSearch() {
    this.search.emit(this.searchObj);
  }
```

**Date-range-picker-chart-container.html**

```
<date-range-picker-chart
  (onSearch)="onSearch2($event)"
></date-range-picker-chart>
```

**Date-range-picker-chart-container.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {}
onSearch2(value) {
    console.log(value); // this doesn't display nothing.
  }
```

Can someone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sub-component triggers the event "search" (`this.search.emit(this.searchObj);`), whereas the parent listens to "onSearch" (`(onSearch)="onSearch2($event)"`).

Change your parent to `(search)="onSearch2($event)"`

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine except the name of the event that you're bound to.

```js
@Output() search: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
          ------
            ^
            |__ Name of the event
```

The parent component (*date-range-picker-chart-container.ts*) has no context of the function `onSearch()` in the child component (*date-range-picker-chart.ts*). You just need to switch the event binding

```html
<date-range-picker-chart (search)="onSearch2($event)">
</date-range-picker-chart>
```

Also the function in the parent could be `onSearch()` instead of `onSearch2()`. The function names are specific to their classes (the components) and do not overlap.